# moving part of a vector to the front or back

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, data-structures

I have a linear array of `int`, I need to move elements from index `i` to `j`, to the front or back of this array. Example:

```
[1,4,34,67,2,3,15,78]
```

and `i = 3, j = 6` (1 indexed array). I need to move

```
[34,67,2,3]
```

to the front to become

```
[34,67,2,3,1,4,15,78]
```

If I use linked list, the moving part can be done in constant time, but finding the `i`'th and `j`'th element takes linear time. If use `vector<int>`, the moving part takes linear time while finding the `i`'th and `j`'th element take constant time. I need a data structure that can "trade off" between these 2 operations, and do both in log time, like how fenwick trees allow log time for both updating the original array and accessing the prefix sum. Is there such a data structure?

I thought about various possible non linear data structures, but can't get them to work.

Comment: When you "move", do you want to *swap* the values? Or to *copy* the value you "move"? For an example collection of values, what should the result be?

Comment: I want all the stuff from index i to j, all moved to the front, and the stuff from index 1 to i-1, pushed along, so the new array starts from i to j, then 1 to i-1, then j+1 to end.

Comment: So you kind of want to *rotate* a sub-section of the array or vector? Again, please [edit] your question to show us a before and after example.

Comment: And please take the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask]. Also read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You also have to consider the size of the data. For a "reasonably" short vector, linear time is still faster than log time for node based containers. Having all its elements sequentially in the cache is a great advantage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variant of an [order-statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) for this. Essentially, start with a self-balancing tree (I suggest an AA tree or a red-black tree), but one with no order (that is, you can’t use it as a search tree). Then augment each node with the size of its subtree. (This field can be updated in constant time for individual tree rotations, and in O(log n) time for all tree operations.) This allows you to look up the k-th lowest element. To perform a rotation, use a “split” operation to split the tree after the k-th element, then a “join” operation with the results reversed. To perform other block moves, just split it into more pieces and join as needed. That all takes O(log n) time.

Comment: From my understanding, after it's split and joined, the tree might not be balanced, and rebalancing might take linear time. And to update the size of the subtree at each node also takes linear time. Can you explain more on how it works?

Comment: No, split and join (including balancing operations) take logarithmic time. Take a look at the Wikipedia article for red-black trees for details. And take a look at articles on order-statistic trees for why updating the statistic takes logarithmic time (though I can’t see why you’d accept that Fenwick trees have this property and order-statistic trees don’t).

Comment: And you're on your way to reinventing the rope. Which is heavily used by text editors for easily manipulatable text.

Comment: @btilly The rope structure is string-specific and not elegant enough to be worth generalising to other domains. But it would also work here, and is obviously similar.

Comment: @Sneftel It has some string optimizations, but I don't think of it as string-specific. Rather I think of it as optimized for complex multi-level edits and undos. It just so happens that the most common use case for that is text editing.

Comment: @btilly It could be a matter of definition. The rope implementations I’ve seen are heavily targeted towards text editing specifically, with many characters held in a leaf node, eager iterative coalescing, and special treatment of word boundaries. I guess I think of a structure without all that, with one atomic element per node, as just an order-statistic tree.

Comment: @Sneftel Take away the special treatment of word boundaries, and I think that many items in a leaf node is likely a generally good optimization.